# AC charger with battery to work on-the-go?

Tags: battery, charger, portable

I have a tiny Sony DSC-W570 camera. It has a 600mah battery, which does not last long (maybe, enough for 100 pictures or so, depending on outside temps and whether flash is used each time). I have a spare battery as well, but what if I need it to last for the whole day, or even multiple days without a need for an AC socket?

Is there some kind of AC charger on-the-go with built-in battery for 6000-9000mah, which stays in a backpack (for example), where I can stick my smaller battery (through a regular wall charger) and charge it while the backup battery is working? Once drained, switch them, and keep taking pictures.

This way I could increase battery life 10 times. Especially useful for occasions when AC plug is not expected to be available soon (i.e. hiking and similar).

I googled hard before asking this question, and all I found was such chargers with USB connectors, so they are only useful for charging phones (iPhone, Android and the like).

Comment: It can't charge over USB? That's the only way my Sony charges, not a W570 though.

Comment: @PaulCezanne: I wish it could. Mine uses a regular AC wall charger. So I just remove battery from the camera, insert into a charger and plug it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously it's a little easier if you can get a USB charger, but no worries- this is still pretty easy. What you are looking for is a "power pack". These are accessory batteries with USB and/or inverters built in. They are generally designed to charge a laptop on the go, so running small(er) battery chargers is even easier.

[Here's an older model on Amazon with an inverter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000H78YXQ). I can find plenty of newer and better models but they appear to be USB-only.

Comment: +1. Thanks for a new term, now I know how to call *that thing*. I found an [Energizer XP18000](http://www.energizerpowerpacks.com/ca/products/xp18000/), but it uses laptop-like tips, means you cannot connect a regular AC plug. So I either need to find a tip-type charger for my battery or a tip-to-AC plug adapter (which would be the universal solution, of course), kind of the opposite of what's being sold on a large scale on eBay and similar. Can you suggest anything?

Comment: that does 12v and 19v. I bet you can find a cigarette/12V charger for your camera on ebay. The only thing remaining is to find the perfect tip that hooks into the charger. [This is a fairly generic charger](http://www.batteriesplus.com/product/36347-EMPDVU--SON1R1-Battery-Charger/551-0/5113-Digital-Camera-Batteries/658969-Sony/Cyber--Shot-DSC--W570.aspx) that includes a "car outlet". Just replace that cord with the XP18000.

Here's [another option](http://www.amazon.com/Sony-Cyber-shot-DSC-W570-Digital-Battery/dp/B0056IVE6U) (better option, imho). Again, just get a tip for the XP18000.